# What does the mixRGB node do in Dodge mode?

Tags: texturing

Can someone explain to me or point me to the documentation of the MixRGB color dodge mode? I've found the documentation of the MixRGB node but could not find an explanation to what the color dodge does. I'm following along a tutorial and I want to understands what is happening.

Comment: Just a bad idea to use a broken tool in a radiometric-like model such as that with rendering. It should have been removed, disabled, or fundamentally altered for use in rendering.

Comment: From wikipedia, "Blend modes" page: "The Color Dodge blend mode divides the bottom layer by the inverted top layer."  Perfectly precise, and I'd expect Blender to be doing that, atlhough I haven't tested.

Comment: @troy_s I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean

Comment: The formulas for Dodge and Burn come from Photoshop, which in the context is very anachronistic. They are designed to work on values that *do not* represent light, but rather encoded values. Worse, they are designed as display referred formulas, meaning 0-100% display encoded values. This means they are completely incompatible with how render engines process light.